# Destroying dependents in Datamapper

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

Using Datamapper, I have a model Album that has n, :photos which has a Paperclip::Resource

With ActiveRecord I would just have had:

```
has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
```

in my Album model, in order to delete the photos at the same time as the Album, but with Datamapper it seems you have to roll your own. In Sinatra, to delete the album I have:

```
delete '/albums/:id' do
  a = Album.get params[:id] 
  a.destroy
  redirect '/'
end
```

and a before filter in the Album model:

```
before :destroy do
  photos.destroy
end
```

but the before filter is never called.

If I put use the bang method, a.destroy!, the album is destroyed but not the Photos.

No errors are produced and no Exceptions raised.

**UPDATE**

There are errors, but with an empty errors hash:

```
INFO -- : #<DataMapper::Validations::ValidationErrors:0x13740dc @resource=#<Album @id=2 @name="Quaver" @created_at=#<DateTime: 2013-02-07T10:30:36+00:00 (5895194251/2400,0/1,2299161)> @updated_at=#<DateTime: 2013-02-07T10:30:36+00:00 (5895194251/2400,0/1,2299161)>>, @errors={}>
```

So clearly I have validation issues. However I have not set any validations in my Models:

```
class Photo  
  include DataMapper::Resource
  include Paperclip::Resource  

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  property :created_at, DateTime  
  property :updated_at, DateTime

  has_attached_file :data, url: "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                       path: "#    {APP_ROOT}/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  belongs_to :album
end

class Album  
  include DataMapper::Resource  
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :created_at, DateTime  
  property :updated_at, DateTime
  has n, :photos

  before :destroy do
    photos.destroy
  end
end
```

So the before filter is not being called because of the ValidationErrors, but where do they come from when they are not explicitly set?

Any help, gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seem https://github.com/datamapper/dm-constraints?

Comment: Hi Matt. Yes I have; but I am really trying to understand why the before filter isn't even called here. It's a learning exercise. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently when you use:

```
require 'data_mapper'
```

you are implicitly using dm-constraints, which protects dependent models by default. Simply giving permission to destroy (much like ActiveRecord) does the trick:

```
has n, :photos, constraint: :destroy
```

Damn that hurt!

Comment: FWIW: The `dm-core` gem does not include `dm-constraints`.  That has to be included separately.